# Spaces in collection name for Firebase Firestore security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

For example I have a collection "sales associates". I am trying to write the security rule:

```
allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/sales associates/$(request.auth.uid));
```

But I am getting an error because "sales associates" has a space in it. How do you write in the collection name with a space? Writing quotes around sales associates does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put quotes around the entire thing:

```
allow read: if exists("/databases/$(database)/documents/sales associates/$(request.auth.uid)");
```

Comment: getting an "Error running simulation" error with the simulator. also apparently having chars like `|`, `;` and even `-` in the collection name return a `Simulated read denied` with no errors. please fix or document!

Answer (score 3):

I was strugling with this and i finally wrote to Google for support. This is what i got back:

> For your use-case of using the get() method with collections and/or documents with spaces in their name, you can abstract the get() method inside a custom function so that it deals with string variables instead of string literals. Below is an exaggerated example of how this can be done:

```
match /collection%20with%20space/{doc}/subcollection%20with%20space/{subDoc} {
  allow read, write: 
      if getDoc("collection with space", doc).data['field with space'] == "foo";
}

function getDoc(collectionString, documentString) {
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(collectionString)/$(documentString));    
}
```

> While the rules simulator may run into issues, it should work properly with the live SDKs.

And indeed the simulator was throwing an error but running the app actually worked.