# Firestore security rules with spaces in path

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to create a firestore rule for a sub collection called "Test Cases". Since firestore rules aren't written in javascript, I can't seem to get the path after match to accept a space without an error.

I've tried quotes, backslashes for escape characters, and putting the whole path in quotes. I haven't found anything for this in the firestore documentation or on stack overflow.

How can I allow a spaces in the path after match, in the example below, in the path including "Test Cases"?

```
service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /companies/{company} {
      allow read: if getUserCompany() == company || userHasAnyRole(['Super', 'Manager']);
      allow write: if getUserCompany() == company || userHasAnyRole(['Super', 'Manager']); 

      match /Test Cases/{tests} {
        allow read, write: if isSignedIn();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is it actually possible to have a space in a path?

Comment: Yes, it works well elsewhere. I have some documents who's names come from clients that have spaces, and they work fine when passed as a wildcard. It's just when I need to specify the specific path that I have a problem.

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48192625/spaces-in-collection-name-for-firebase-firestore-security-rules as an example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to fire base support:

To fix this, you can encode the space within security rules using %20. So the rules would be:

```
Service cloud.firestore { 

match /databases/{database}/documents { 

match /companies/{company} { 
allow read: if getUserCompany() == company || userHasAnyRole(['Super', 'Manager']); 
allow write: if getUserCompany() == company || userHasAnyRole(['Super', 'Manager']); 

match /Test%20Cases/{tests} {                      <------- 
allow read, write: if isSignedIn(); 
} 
} 
}
```

I tried it and worked for me. Please give it a try and let us know if you have any issues.

Comment: what is the case if there is a "+" ?

Comment: @JeevaCanessane If the document has a "+", then the security rule will need the URL encoded value of "+", which is `%2B`. https://www.urlencoder.org/ is a helpful tool for finding other URL encoded values.