# How do you remove a key that has a space in it? (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I stored something in firebase, and the key contains a space. example: "CS 1332". I am trying to remove it but I think there is a problem because of the space. It is converting it to %20 which might not be how firebase represent spaces.

```
let ref = REF_USERS.child(uid).child("classes").child("CS 1332")

ref.removeValue()
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you shared that should cause the space to be encoded to `%20`. How did you determine that that is what's happening?

Comment: When I run this line: print(ref.description())
It prints this (I replaced part of it in the comment with dots):
https://hu(.........)/classes/AS%202220

Answer (score 0):

There are a few examples using spaces in things like rules and collections.

- [In the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50708145/firestore-security-rules-with-spaces-in-path)

While rules require the path to be "encoded", [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53048641/10747134) lead me to find [this documentation for best practices](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#field_names) from the Firebase team. You should be able to escape the path with backticks to perform that type of operation on a path with a space.

Please try:

```
let ref = REF_USERS.child(uid).child("classes").child("`CS 1332`")

ref.removeValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't allow you to rename keys, but you could just pull the particular nodes that have an issue and re-save them to the database with a new key, deleting the data from the old one as you go. Once the data within that old key is deleted, firebase will clean up the empty key itself.

Comment: Sorry I was not very clear. I am trying to delete the key, not the space. I want to remove the key value pair completely.

Comment: I see. Are there many instances  of this issue, or only a single instance? can you log the contents of the snapshot and see if there's any unusual characters in the console? Assuming you want to delete it programmatically, have you given the required permission for that in the firebase rules?

Comment: No unusual character. And here are my permissions:
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }